# OrientDb DROP PROPERTY does not remove the property values in records

Tags: orientdb

As per OrientDB docs it says

> The Drop Property command removes a property from the schema. This
>   doesn't remove the property values in records, but just change the
>   schema information. Records will continue to have the property values
>   if any.

This is creating some issues in my code, making app throw null pointer exception for dropped properties. Is there any way to drop property and remove values from existing records too.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Found the solution [here](http://orient-database.narkive.com/HjiHiH0d/orientdb-how-to-delete-a-property-of-a-schema-less-document)

To remove property from existing records to run following query:

```
UPDATE <class> REMOVE <PROPERTY> WHERE <CONDITION>
```